# How can I add examples to rspec at runtime?

Tags: ruby, runtime, rspec, dynamic

I am trying to write a spec were the number of examples i.e. 'it "should ..." do' are determined at runtime. I tried putting the 'it' method in my own method so that I could call it multiple times:

```
def new_method(test)  
    it "#{test} should... " do  
    end  
end
```

However, the 'it' method is not available from the current Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass instance.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid code duplication, sometimes I do something like this:

```
describe SomeOjbect do
  %w(a b c d e f g).each do |val|
    it "should have a value of #{val}" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Which would create 7 examples in the spec. I suppose if you really were dead-set on using a method, you could do something like this:

```
def new_method(grp, test)
  grp.instance_eval do
    it "#{test} should..." do
      # ...
    end
  end
end

describe SomeObject do
  new_method(self, "a")
  new_method(self, "b")
  new_method(self, "c")
  new_method(self, "d")
  # ...
end
```

Here you pass `self`, which is the scope of the `describe` block, and `instance_eval` lets you execute code as if you were in that block, so the `it` method is available.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Thanks for the examples. They work if you know at development time how many examples you need to run. Unfortunately, in my case, I need to determine this at runtime.

Comment: Well I also described how to make your `new_method` idea work.